# Why @api.doc decorator python flask restplus not update the changes I make?

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restplus

I using Flask-Restplus to develop my API. I wanna to ask,why the `@api.doc` decorator not update my changes in the Swagger UI?

Here is the endpoint I define

```
@api.route('/create_user')
class User(Resource):
    @api.response(201, 'User successfully created.')
    @api.doc('create a new user')
    @api.expect(_user, validate=True)
    @api.marshal_list_with(_user, envelope='data')
    def post(self):
        """Creates a new User """
        data = request.json
        return create_user(data=data)


@api.route('/get_user_list')
class UserList(Resource):
    @api.doc('list_of_registered') //even I change here,in Swagger is still not update
    @api.marshal_list_with(_user, envelope='data')
    def get(self):
        """List all registered users"""
        return get_all_users()

@api.route('/create_product')
class Product(Resource):
    @api.response(201, 'Product successfully created.')
    @api.doc('12345678') //here I state to this
    @api.expect(_product, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        """Creates a new User """
        data = request.json
        return create_product(data=data)
```

So here is the result in my browser:

[image]

As you can see here,the doc is not updating according the string I define in `@api.doc` decorator.

So anyone can let me know why is this happen? And how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in fact the documentation that it generates first of the comment which follows directly the declaration of your function

change that:

```
@api.route('/create_product')
class Product(Resource):
    @api.response(201, 'Product successfully created.')
    @api.doc('12345678') //here I state to this
    @api.expect(_product, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        """Creates a new User """
        data = request.json
        return create_product(data=data)
```

To that:

```
@api.route('/create_product')
class Product(Resource):
    @api.response(201, 'Product successfully created.')
    @api.doc('12345678') //here I state to this
    @api.expect(_product, validate=True)
    def post(self):
        """Creates a new Product """
        data = request.json
        return create_product(data=data)
```

Comment: so means that the documentation will generate from the comment in function??If no comment in function,then only it will generate from `@api.doc` am I right??

Comment: not sorry I was wrong, he only takes this documentation as commentary

Comment: but when it doesnt have comment in the function,the documentation in browser direct empty,but not generate form api.doc

Comment: yes it's true I just tested and it does not use the one that is specified trought @api.doc

Comment: you can check the answer to help others who have the same problem

Comment: I have the same bug using the api.expect or api.doc(body) used by model. Why the model don't updated in documentation? Any idea @wambakevin

Comment: @TiagoBarreto can I see your code to try to find the error?

Comment: What I'd really like to know is why I can't even find (easily) in the latest flask-restplus documentation a mention of the fact that the method descriptions are taken from the block comment following the method declaration, let alone how to override that. There's nothing in the [Swagger documentation section](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html) and I would have thought that a search on "comment" would have turned up something. What am I missing?

Comment: @flayman This feature is only mentioned in some github issues: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/137, https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/215, https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/249
It should also be noted that there is a new fork https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ .